# Removing SQL Server Express 2008 Instances

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can SQL Server 2005 Instances be manually removed (if uninstall does not clean them up)?

Comment: I believe this may happened due to installation I received of VS2005 which includes MSSQLEXPRESS 2005 without compatibility fixes for Vista (or Windows 7 in my case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long searches and trying to delete things from registry I found the following solution:

Delete SQLEXPRESS from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names

Delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1

Delete entire branch HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90

To remove actual databases, delete folder:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1

Disclaimer: Use at your own risk.

Comment: (Asked question and answered to document answer for future troubleshooters.)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft lists other cleanup steps to also consider on MSDN, besides those few registry keys to fully cleanup an instance of SQL Server 2005 manually - 
This may also help from a SQL Server 2005 Express standpoint -http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909967

This blog post has an alternate approach that I have not tried

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2005/09/13/465401.aspx And this

Comment: Tried those both before deleting those keys - neither worked for me.

Comment: Interesting, just deleting the registry keys only that you mention and not doing everything won't be as clean as following the KB article though, just FYI for anyone reading this thread.

Comment: Yeh, it is best to try the KB first. Then delete registry keys if that doesn't work.